# HttpResponse - Closing associated stream does not release socket

Tags: java, apache, sockets, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

Trying to use HttpClient to post a HttpRequest and receive HttpResponse. I'm doing the following on HttpResponse

```
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
//consume the data here
is.close();
```

On doing `is.close()` the socket doesn't seem to be closed. I tracked the port number using TCPView. I can see that the local port used to send the HttpRequest is in ESTABLISHED state. It goes down after a few minutes not immediately after I call `is.close()`.

Comment: It is doing connection pooling. If you don't want that, use whatever API is provided to disable HTTP keep-alive for this request.

Comment: Disabling keep-alive did not bring down the socket immediately. HttpConnectionParams.setSoKeepalive(params, false); did not work. I read the documentation that the socket must be closed immediately after the stream is closed? I can see many port kept open for a while.